# Is there any web interface for message queue MySQL adapter in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, message-queue

Is there any web interface for "message queue MySQL adapter" in Magento 2 ?

I have searched that, but cannot find anything (But no result for searches does not mean it doesn't exist though)

[magento 2 doc where the MySQL adapter is mentionned](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/message-queues/message-queues.html*)

The version of Magento is **Magento Community Edition 2.2**

In the end, I wish to use this message queue system/'message broker', as I cannot install RabbitMQ on the server.

Comment: What do you mean by interface? Define what you mean by that?

Comment: And yes there are implementation for the community edition. This is one of them: https://github.com/renatocason/magento2-module-mq

Comment: Also you don't have to install RabbitMQ on the same server. It can be on a separate server.

Comment: Too bad you've deleted your answer, I could have accepted it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yeah the answer only covered EE queues.